# find max from multiple value in column

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables. Users, PC, Departments
Users have DepartmentID and PCID columns that contains as ID in Departments and PCID in users.

I need select pc.id from department which users have maximum sum of salary

I made some attempt at the problem.

```
WITH cte AS (select s.did, max(Sum_Salary) as Sum_Salary from (select d.ID as did ,sum(u.Salary) as Sum_Salary from dbo.users u 
inner join Departments d on u.DepartmentID=d.id 
group by d.ID ) s group by s.did), cte2 as (select cte.did, cte.Sum_Salary as maxx from cte where Sum_Salary=(select max(Sum_Salary) from cte))
select cte2.did,cte2.maxx,pc.id as pc_id from cte2
inner join users u on cte2.did=u.DepartmentID 
inner join PC on u.PCID=PC.id
;
```

That works. I am interesting in more effective algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I used two ctes: The first one to calculate the sum of salary in each combination (department, user), the second one to find the maximum sum of the salary in the first cte. Then I join the two cte and only pick those PCID with the maximum sum of salary.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT d.id, u.PCID, SUM(u.Salary) AS Sum_Salary
  FROM users u JOIN Departments d ON u.DepartmentID = d.id
  GROUP BY d.id, u.PCID
), cte1 AS (
SELECT cte.id AS DeptID, MAX(Sum_Salary) AS Max_Sum_Salary 
FROM cte
GROUP BY cte.id)
SELECT cte1.DeptID, cte.PCID, d.name
FROM cte 
JOIN cte1 ON cte1.DeptID = cte.id AND cte.Sum_Salary=cte1.Max_Sum_Salary
JOIN Departments d ON d.id = cte1.DeptID
```

Comment: I try same thing but instead of two "AS" I used select from select. I would try your construction with self join and learn more about multiple  "group by" condittion.

Comment: Big sorry. I formulated wrong. I need select pc.id from department which users have maximum sum of salary

Comment: What is the relation between pc.id and department? pc.id and users? Can you explain them in words?

Comment: I remade my query. It works. But I want see another realizations.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the salary within department, can return the first user

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select d.Name as dname,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY u.DepartmentID ORDER BY u.Salary desc) AS SeqNO
    FROM dbo.users u
    inner join Departments d on u.DepartmentID=d.id
    inner join PC on u.PCID=PC.id
    where u.salary>500 
) AS t WHERE t.SeqNO=1
```

Comment: Thanks. Would Ttry later,

Comment: Big sorry. I formulated wrong. I need select pc.id from department which users have maximum sum of salary

Comment: I remade my query. It works. But I want see another realizations.